# How to get link to translated content in ImpressPages 3.9?

Tags: translation, impresspages

I got a problem creating a multi-languages website with ImpressPages (v 3.9).

I created 3 languages in admin: French, English and German. I got many pages that I've translated into 3 languages using "generateManagedText()" function.

I've also created 3 menus as using one for each languages.

My problem is: how can I generate links to inline-translated pages?

I got a language selector generated with this line:

```
echo $this->generateBlock('ipLanguages');
```

But the link are just redirecting to each homepage.

I would like to get an easy way to show link to each translated version in all website, could you get me some advises please?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot generate a link to inline managed elements. Only pages have links. All the links you have is from Menu management.

Each language has its own menus and they don't have any relation with other language. Which means, you may have many pages in one language and only a few in the other.

Comment: Thank you for reply but I have another question: when editing an inline managed text, I have 3 tabs (one for each language).

It seems I can only display content of current language, or can I get other tabs' content programmatically?